# Maven phases : Generate Sources, Process Sources, Process Classes

Tags: maven

It is not clear what happens in these phases, the documentation describes these phases very concisely. Do you need some plugins for the correct operation of these phases? Or do they themselves initially carry out some kind of functionality?

I studied https://maven.apache.org/ but these phases are not really parsed there in detail.

I want to understand how the phases of Generate Sources, Process Sources, Process Classes in Maven work.

Comment: The phase generate-source is intended to do some code generations which is used by plugins like antlr or other plugins which are generating code. The process-sources is running afterwards to make it possible to change the generated code somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Note that without additional plugins, most of the phases are empty (i.e. do nothing).

They are intended to be used for certain plugins, if you require those plugin (as khmarbaise said). So if you add a plugin for source code generation to your POM, you would attach it to the phase `generate-sources` (if it does not do so automatically).